# Trying to make an NPM package

Tags: javascript

Basically, im trying to make a package that would look like this in my main project file

```js
const package = require("package");
const newPackage = new package({
  param: 'value',
  otherParam: 'otherValue'
});
```

and then in every other project file I could use

```js
const { someFunction } = require('package')

someFunction()
```

and then the `SomeFunction()` function should return `value` and `otherValue`
without needing to do

```js
const package = require("package");
const newPackage = new package({
  param: 'value',
  otherParam: 'otherValue'
});

newPackage.someFunction()
```

in every project file.

Im not sure how to do this or if this is even possible, but would love something that would work like (or similar to) this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be *possible* to do this, it would involve some pretty smelly code - the package would have to have calling the constructor produce side-effects and return an unused instance. For a very slight tweak, consider instead if you could change the init code from

```
const package = require("package");
const newPackage = new package({
  param: 'value',
  otherParam: 'otherValue'
});
```

to something like

```
const { init } = require("package");
init({
  param: 'value',
  otherParam: 'otherValue'
});
```

That would be quite doable and not smelly. Put a variable in the package's scope that gets assigned to when `init` is called, and return that variable when `someFunction` is called.

```
let initObj;
module.exports = {
  init(obj) {
    initObj = obj;
  },
  someFunction() {
    return initObj;
  }
};
```

Live snippet:

```js
const theModule = (() => {
  let initObj;
  return {
    init(obj) {
      initObj = obj;
    },
    someFunction() {
      return initObj;
    }
  }
})();

theModule.init({
  param: 'value',
  otherParam: 'otherValue'
});

console.log(theModule.someFunction());
```

Comment: but then I would have to write the `init` in every file in order for the `value` and `otherValue` to stay the same as they are in the main project file

Comment: No, you would only have to write `init` once, somewhere near your entry point, and then every other file would only have to import the `someFunction`.

Comment: Ive tried doing this, but it just returns undefined instead of `{ param: 'value', otherParam: 'otherValue' }`

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine for me. Are you sure you're running your modules in the correct order? Call `init` first, and only after that call `someFunction`

Comment: It works fine in the Main file, where i run`init` with the params, but then in other files that i only import the package it returns undefined

Comment: It sounds like your main file isn't running first. Make sure that it runs first, and that other modules only run afterwards. A good way to manage this sort of thing is to always export *functions*, and to not have code that contains side-effects on the top level. For example, inside a module. do: `module.exports.runThisModule = () => { /* code here */ }`, and then import and call that function from elsewhere.